# Running rails on a Production mode in webrick server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my current ruby on rails project, I am using webrick (default) server for development. I have a separate server for testing the application and I want to set the environment to Products in it. I used the following line to run the server in production mode.

```
rails s -e production
```

The issue is, it works perfectly if its in the development mode, but in server mode I'm getting following error:

```
Started GET "/" for 172.20.7.94 at Thu Jun 07 10:35:45 +0530 2012
  Processing by FrontendController#dashboard as HTML
Rendered frontend/dashboard.html.erb within layouts/frontend (3.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 50ms (Views: 22.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/assets/frontend-datauri.css" for 172.20.7.94 at Thu Jun 07 10:35:4
6 +0530 2012
  Processing by Jammit::Controller#package as HTML
  Parameters: {"extension"=>"css", "package"=>"frontend-datauri"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 190ms

NameError (uninitialized constant POpen4::Open4):


Started GET "/assets/frontend.js" for 172.20.7.94 at Thu Jun 07 10:35:46 +0530 2
012
  Processing by Jammit::Controller#package as
  Parameters: {"extension"=>"js", "package"=>"frontend"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 105ms

NameError (uninitialized constant POpen4::Open4):
```

I am using Jammit and POpen4 and my rails version is: 3.0.9. Ruby version 1.8.7. I can't currently upgrade the version as several other developers are involved in the project. Can anybody give me a solution for this.

Thanks

Comment: First thing: using webrick in production is a bad idea. It hasn't been designed for that and has very poor performances. Use `thin`, `unicorn`, ... Second thing: it seems that the gem POpen4 is not present in your bundle. Have you put your POpen4 gem in a `:development` group only in your gem file ? Or have run `bundle install` excluding production gem wit a `--without` option ?

Comment: Actually I haven't mentioned anything for POpen4 in Gemfile also yes using webrick for production is not a good idea, but I'm using here on a testing server to make sure it works perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot for everyone who tried to help me regarding this issue. I installed CentOS and everything's have fixed and running smoothly.

That might be some issue with the Windows server 2008 which I was using previously

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to specify your dependencies in your Gemfile.

Gemfile:

```
...
gem 'popen4'
...
```

and then run `bundle install` to create a specific bundle of gems for your app.

Otherwise your app relies on what you have installed locally on your machine (I suppose via `gem install popen4`).

Here you production machine doesn't have the gem POpen4 installed on it... So the other quick (but no recommended) solution is to install the gem manually on your production machine with `gem install popen4`.

Comment: I added it and still no luck for that :( I assume the issue is from Jammit compressor as it uses yui-compressor there will be an issue in there

Comment: @Mujahid hum ok I've just understood that popen4 is not one of your dependencies but a dependency of jammit > yui-compressor... So you should to rename your question, it's not at all a Webrick issue ;) Still, your bundle does not contain POpen4... you can try to remove your `Gemfile.lock` file and run `bundle install` to recompute the dependencies...

Comment: @Mujahid when I say you to `run bundle install` ==> on your production machine, not on your local dev one.

Comment: I did it, all the things that you've mentioned but still no luck :(